# Configure distant terminal behaviour

Tags: debian, terminal, console, vps

I just installed debian 7 on a VPS, created users, configured ssh ..etc

The problem is that the terminal application changed its behavior just after connecting with my new username:

- Autocompletion not working (I edited /etc/bash.bashrc for that but it dosen't works)
- I can't use keyboard shortcuts like I always used to :
  For example CTRL-l, or CTRL-R or even up/down for commands history , left/right to move within the same command and start/end keys.

When I use those shortcuts I've got those chars:

```
$ ^[[C^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[A^[[B^[[A
```

Well, it not productive at all ! 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an answer, the new created user was having `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

So I did :

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash my_new_user
```

Comment: It's really `dash`. `sh` is symlink to `dash`.

Answer (score 0):

[Debian 7 default shell](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) is `dash`, so you can not get some features that `bash` provides.

You can change `DSHELL` config in `/etc/adduser.conf` to change user default shell when using `adduser`:

```
# The DSHELL variable specifies the default login shell on your            
# system.                                                                  
DSHELL=/bin/bash
```

If you use `useradd`, change `SHELL` config in `/etc/default/useradd`:

```
# The SHELL variable specifies the default login shell on your                  
# system.                                                                       
# Similar to DHSELL in adduser. However, we use "sh" here because               
# useradd is a low level utility and should be as general                       
# as possible                                                                   
SHELL=/bin/sh
```

Or use `-s` option of `useradd` command:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash username
```

For bash completetion, you must install `bash-completion` package from repo:

```
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

Comment: DSHELL is set by default to /bin/bash !

Comment: Did you use `adduser` or `useradd` to add user?

Comment: Useradd (I think), does this change anything ?

Comment: @4m1nh4j1: Yes, `useradd` default shell (if not specify by `-s` option) is set in `/etc/default/useradd`, it's `/bin/sh`. In Debian system, `adduser` is a Perl script, while in `Redhat/Centos` system, `adduser` is symlink to `useradd`.